# Trouble with != in C#

Tags: c#, textbox

So I'm having trouble using the "!=" expression.

```
private void EnterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox1.Text == null)
    {
        TextBox1.Text != TextBox2.Text
    }
    else
    {
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
        TextBox1.Text = "";
    }
```

Here's how it works: The User can type text into "TextBox1" and that text will appear on the form in "TextBox2". I am trying to make it to where if "TextBox1" is empty then "TextBox2" doesn't change. Im getting the error here:

```
  TextBox1.Text != TextBox2.Text
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, its probably simple. But I'm new to this... Thanks for any help! I'm using Visual Studios C# 2010 Express

Comment: What error are you getting there?

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues -

First, you are missing a semi-colon (`;`) at the end of the line, so it's not a valid statement in C#.

Second, a comparison (`!=`) doesn't make sense on it's own.  Given your description of your requirements, I believe you want:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
{
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    TextBox1.Text = "";
}
```

Basically, only do something is the string isn't empty.  There is no need for an `else` case here, as you don't want to perform any action in that case.

Comment: Yeah I have the semi-colon in my actual code, i just left it out by accident when i pasted. But thanks guys! Good learning experience.

Comment: @brettsalyer The big thing is `!=` is used for doing a comparison - it says "are the two things not equal" and returns a boolean value.  This means, in practice, it's almost always used within an `if()` statement, not on its own, where it makes no sense (since you're not using the result).

Answer (score 2):

The TextBox1.Text should never be null.

check for `string.Empty`.

eg:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
{
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    TextBox1.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: actually, !string.Isnullorempty(TextBox1.Text) would be better

Comment: agreed, I have corrected incorrect casing in your comment :)

Answer (score 2):

In C# `!=` is the negation of the equality operator. Meaning it compares two values and returns true if they're equal and false if they're not. What you're looking for is something more like;

```
  if (TextBox1.Text != TextBox2.Text)
     //the text in these two textboxes is not equal
  else
     // they both have hte same value
```

The definition of equality changes from type to type so keep in mind you will get different results based on what you're comparing.

Comment: I don't think what he is attempting is what you wrote. You made it compilable, but it doesn't meet his requirements.

Comment: @Steve not trying to be mean but what he is attempting makes no sense at all, I can't just infer what he wants. I'm just trying to explain how equality comparisons work on a basic level so that the OP can apply that concept as he sees fit.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I agree, the statement `TextBox1.Text != TextBox2.Text` makes absolutely no sense!

Comment: @evanmcdonnal lol I can understand that, which is why I didn't feel it was necessary to downvote :) (Two diff Steves btw)

Comment: @Steve lol so confusing... Didn't realize your display name didn't have to be unique

Comment: I was just playing.. I did notice the username @Steve and thought it would be fun to muddy the conversation..

Comment: @Steve haha, I would have done the same

Answer (score 0):

The operator `!=` is a `Not Equal To` comparison. That line of code is doing nothing and is missing a `;` so it's more than just useless it's wrong. It sounds like you want something more like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text))
{
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    TextBox1.Text = "";
}
```